# Prove that the sequence is increasing.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to prove that the sequence $M_n$ is increasing and bounded.

Answer (score 2):

$M_2>M_1$. Assume that $M_{n+1}>M_n$. Then $\sqrt{M_{n+1}}>\sqrt{M_n}$. Then, $5+\sqrt{M_{n+1}}>5+\sqrt{M_n}$. Thus, $\sqrt{5+\sqrt{M_{n+1}}}>\sqrt{5+\sqrt{M_n}}$. Therefore, $M_{n+2}>M_{n+1}$. By induction, the sequence is increasing.

And yes, if you proved that $M_n<5$, then you have proved that it is bounded.

For the sake of completion, let me say:

It is bounded above and increasing, thus it has a limit $a$.

$\lim_{n\to\infty}M_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{5+\sqrt{M_n}}$

$a=\sqrt{5+\sqrt{a}}$.

$a^2=5+\sqrt{a}$. Let $a=t^2$, $t^4=5+t$.

Solving the quartic equation, we get a complicated expression of a solution for $t$, then square it to get $a$. You can check the solution on Wolfram if you want to see how it looks.